# Multiple Trigger AWS Lambda or Step Function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-step-functions

I'm currently working with a Lambda which receives some user and video(filename) data and stores them in a RDS database.

At the same time, the video is uploaded to a S3 bucket, outside this lambda function to reduce cost, as the upload can take a while.

After the video is uploaded, I need to run FFMPEG to get some extra information, like video duration, thumbnail, etc. When FFMPEG function is done, it needs to send the information to the RDS database.

My problem is that sometimes the first step which stores the data in RDS database takes longer than the upload+FFMPEG steps, so when it tries to store the new data, there isn't a record on the database for it.

I would like to avoid creating the record on RDS with just the filename+ffmpeg data, and then only update it.

So is there anyway I can start a Lambda only after the RDS record is created AND the file upload to S3 bucket is finished? In the image it may be cleared to understand what I need.

Thanks in advance

[image: Possible Workflow]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question and for your interest in Step Functions!

It sounds like your workaround would require you to perform some sort of **polling** to make sure that the prerequisite steps have completed before executing your final state.

Have a look at this diagram from [Poll for Job Status (Lambda, AWS Batch) - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-project-job-poller.html) to see if this would be a helpful design pattern (tweaked for your specific use case):

[image: Step Functions]